# How can I set multiple files content into columns?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to display the 3 files content into column format. I've tried:

```bash
pr -mts'' file1 file2 file3 |  column -t
```

`file1` has 5 rows, `file2` has 3 rows, `file3` has 5 rows, but the problem is `file3` last 2 rows are overlapping with `file2` column.

How can I format the perfect columns without mismatching the file content?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you wanted.

```
pr -mT -w 120 file[123]
```

Comment: hurray!!!you are a saver. i was trying this since long days. thank you so much